# SVG responsive curve line

Tags: css, canvas, svg, drawing, line

I try to centered the svg line with svg icon, the line should draw across the svg icons, but not overlap them. How to make it responsive, depend on the container width. Is there any solution, canvas or after pseudo classes. The line and icon should be centered, even I add aditional conten to thish block. [codepen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/zZqZzN)

```
<div class="wrapper text-center">

  <svg class="red svg-1 svg-2" width=100% height=100% >
       <path  d="M 50 0 l 0 27 q 0 50 50 50 l 1000 0 q 50 0 50 50 l 0 50" stroke="#d4d4d4" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
    </svg>
  <div class="row">        

    <div class="columns medium-4"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="75.001px" height="75px" viewBox="0 0 75.001 75"
        enable-background="new 0 0 75.001 75" xml:space="preserve">
<switch>
    <foreignObject requiredExtensions="&ns_ai;" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
        <i:pgfRef  xlink:href="#adobe_illustrator_pgf">
        </i:pgfRef>
    </foreignObject>
    <g i:extraneous="self">
        <g>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M64.017,10.984C56.934,3.9,47.517,0,37.5,0S18.067,3.901,10.984,10.984S0,27.484,0,37.5
                c0,10.017,3.901,19.433,10.984,26.517C18.067,71.1,27.483,75,37.5,75s19.434-3.9,26.517-10.982
                c7.083-7.084,10.984-16.5,10.984-26.517C75.001,27.484,71.1,18.067,64.017,10.984z M72.001,37.5c0,2.656-0.308,5.264-0.889,7.791
                l-6.286-7.793l6.278-7.823C71.69,32.212,72.001,34.832,72.001,37.5z M13.105,13.105C19.622,6.588,28.285,3,37.5,3
                s17.879,3.588,24.396,10.105c3.739,3.739,6.509,8.188,8.195,13.04l-7.043,8.775c-5.706-8.429-15.305-13.585-25.547-13.585
                S17.66,26.491,11.954,34.92L4.91,26.144C6.597,21.292,9.366,16.844,13.105,13.105z M61.151,37.5
                c-5.063,8.144-14.045,13.166-23.65,13.166S18.914,45.645,13.851,37.5c5.063-8.144,14.045-13.166,23.65-13.166
                S56.088,29.357,61.151,37.5z M3,37.5c0-2.669,0.311-5.289,0.896-7.827l6.279,7.824l-6.287,7.795C3.308,42.766,3,40.157,3,37.5z
                 M61.896,61.896C55.379,68.412,46.715,72,37.5,72s-17.878-3.588-24.395-10.104c-3.749-3.75-6.522-8.211-8.208-13.078l7.053-8.742
                c5.706,8.432,15.307,13.59,25.551,13.59s19.845-5.158,25.551-13.59l7.052,8.742C68.419,53.685,65.645,58.146,61.896,61.896z"/>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M37.501,26.833c-5.882,0-10.667,4.785-10.667,10.667c0,5.881,4.785,10.666,10.667,10.666
                c5.881,0,10.666-4.784,10.666-10.666C48.167,31.619,43.382,26.833,37.501,26.833z M37.501,45.166
                c-4.228,0-7.667-3.438-7.667-7.666c0-4.228,3.439-7.667,7.667-7.667s7.666,3.439,7.666,7.667
                C45.167,41.728,41.729,45.166,37.501,45.166z"/>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M37.501,34.583c-1.608,0-2.917,1.309-2.917,2.917c0,1.608,1.309,2.916,2.917,2.916
                c1.607,0,2.916-1.308,2.916-2.916C40.417,35.892,39.108,34.583,37.501,34.583z"/>


        </g>
    </g>
</switch>
</svg></div>

    <div class="columns medium-4"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="74.983px" height="75.001px" viewBox="0 0 74.983 75.001"
        enable-background="new 0 0 74.983 75.001" xml:space="preserve">
<switch>
    <foreignObject requiredExtensions="&ns_ai;" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
        <i:pgfRef  xlink:href="#adobe_illustrator_pgf">
        </i:pgfRef>
    </foreignObject>
    <g i:extraneous="self">
        <g>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M37.5,75.001c-10.017,0-19.433-3.9-26.516-10.983S0,47.518,0,37.501s3.901-19.434,10.984-26.517
                S27.483,0,37.5,0c10.016,0,19.434,3.901,26.516,10.984c14.621,14.621,14.621,38.412,0,53.033
                C56.934,71.101,47.516,75.001,37.5,75.001z M37.5,3c-9.215,0-17.878,3.589-24.395,10.105c-13.451,13.452-13.451,35.339,0,48.791
                c6.517,6.516,15.18,10.104,24.395,10.104c9.215,0,17.879-3.589,24.395-10.104C68.413,55.38,72,46.716,72,37.501
                s-3.588-17.879-10.105-24.396C55.379,6.589,46.715,3,37.5,3z"/>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M37.501,53.667c-10.964,0-21.194-5.906-26.697-15.415c-0.27-0.465-0.27-1.037,0-1.502
                c5.503-9.509,15.733-15.415,26.697-15.415c10.964,0,21.195,5.906,26.697,15.415c0.27,0.465,0.27,1.037,0,1.502
                C58.696,47.761,48.465,53.667,37.501,53.667z M13.851,37.501c5.063,8.144,14.045,13.166,23.65,13.166
                c9.605,0,18.587-5.022,23.65-13.166c-5.062-8.144-14.045-13.166-23.65-13.166C27.896,24.335,18.914,29.357,13.851,37.501z"/>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M37.501,48.167c-5.882,0-10.667-4.785-10.667-10.666c0-5.882,4.785-10.667,10.667-10.667
                c5.88,0,10.666,4.785,10.666,10.667C48.167,43.382,43.381,48.167,37.501,48.167z M37.501,29.834
                c-4.228,0-7.667,3.439-7.667,7.667s3.439,7.666,7.667,7.666c4.228,0,7.666-3.438,7.666-7.666S41.729,29.834,37.501,29.834z"/>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M37.501,40.417c-1.608,0-2.917-1.309-2.917-2.916c0-1.608,1.309-2.917,2.917-2.917
                c1.607,0,2.916,1.309,2.916,2.917C40.417,39.108,39.108,40.417,37.501,40.417z"/>



        </g>
    </g>
</switch>
</svg></div>
    <div class="columns medium-4">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="74.963px" height="75px" viewBox="0 0 74.963 75" enable-background="new 0 0 74.963 75"
        xml:space="preserve">
<switch>
    <foreignObject requiredExtensions="&ns_ai;" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
        <i:pgfRef  xlink:href="#adobe_illustrator_pgf">
        </i:pgfRef>
    </foreignObject>
    <g i:extraneous="self">
        <g>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M63.998,10.984C56.914,3.9,47.497,0,37.48,0S18.048,3.901,10.965,10.984
                c-14.62,14.621-14.62,38.412,0,53.033C18.048,71.1,27.464,75,37.48,75s19.434-3.9,26.518-10.983
                C78.618,49.396,78.618,25.605,63.998,10.984z M61.877,61.896C55.36,68.412,46.696,72,37.48,72
                c-9.215,0-17.878-3.589-24.395-10.104c-13.45-13.451-13.45-35.339,0-48.791C19.603,6.588,28.266,3,37.48,3
                c9.216,0,17.88,3.588,24.396,10.105C75.327,26.557,75.327,48.445,61.877,61.896z"/>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M34.736,37.307H17.043c-0.828,0-1.5,0.671-1.5,1.5V56.5c0,0.829,0.672,1.5,1.5,1.5h17.693
                c0.828,0,1.5-0.671,1.5-1.5V38.806C36.236,37.978,35.564,37.307,34.736,37.307z M33.236,55H18.543V40.306h14.693V55z"/>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M57.92,37.307H40.227c-0.828,0-1.5,0.671-1.5,1.5V56.5c0,0.829,0.672,1.5,1.5,1.5H57.92
                c0.828,0,1.5-0.671,1.5-1.5V38.806C59.42,37.978,58.748,37.307,57.92,37.307z M56.42,55H41.727V40.306H56.42V55z"/>
            <path fill="#FFD100" d="M47.828,33.667V15.974c0-0.829-0.672-1.5-1.5-1.5H28.635c-0.828,0-1.5,0.671-1.5,1.5v17.693                c0,0.829,0.672,1.5,1.5,1.5h17.693C47.156,35.167,47.828,34.496,47.828,33.667z M44.828,32.167H30.135V17.474h14.693V32.167z"/>

        </g>
    </g>
  </switch>
  </svg></div>

     <!-- LINES Це тимчасово так зліва направо однією лінією, потрібно буде дві лінії з центра вліво і друга з центра вправо-->
<!--     <svg class="red svg-1 svg-2" width=100% height=100% >
       <path  d="M 50 0 l 0 27 q 0 50 50 50 l 1000 0 q 50 0 50 50 l 0 50" stroke="#d4d4d4" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
    </svg> -->
    <!-- END LINES -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go [Codepen](http://codepen.io/grebre0/pen/LWNWoB)

The idea:

1) use line image as a `background-image`

2) use `background-size: 100% 177px` 100% will stretch the image too full width, 177px is an original height of the image.